# Java Strings : The output of the program is not as expected

Tags: java, string, immutability

```
String s="abc";
String s1=s;
s=s+"d";
System.out.println(s==s1 +" "+ s.equals(s1));
System.out.println(s.equals(s1));
```

The above code is written in java.
I thought the output of the above program might be

```
false false
false
```

but the actual output is

```
false 
false
```

Can anyone explain why is this the output and why not as the previous one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `"Everyone"` include Jon Skeet?  I doubt it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.println(s==s1 +" "+ s.equals(s1));
```

is equivalent to:

```
System.out.println(s==(s1 +" "+ s.equals(s1)));
```

if you used:

```
System.out.println((s==s1) + " " + s.equals(s1));
```

you will get:

```
false false
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets analyse whats happening here:

```
System.out.println(s==s1 +" "+ s.equals(s1));
```

You've got a boolean + string + boolean. But keep in mind that the operators `==` and `+` got different priorities (see http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php).

As you can see the + operator has a higher priority and is therefore executed first.
This causes the following:

```
System.out.println(s == (s1 +" "+ s.equals(s1)) );
```

As you see the string `s1` will be added to `" "` and the remaining `false` boolean.

So you've got

```
System.out.println(s == "someString");
```

which is false and therefore you get `"false"` as an output.